# img2pdf batch script

Tags: shell-script, pdf, conversion

I currently have over 10K folders. Each folder has .png and .jpg images that need to be turned into .pdf files. Files are numerically in order already.

I am looking for speed. I can currently cd into each folder and run

```
img2pdf * -o out.pdf
```

And I get a perfectly created out.pdf in less than a second, even with several hundred images.

My end goal is to automate this in a shell script that can be invoked, so each folder is basically turned into a .pdf file with the filename the same as the old directory like so

```
Directory001/img001.jpg
             img002.jpg
             img003.jpg
OtherDirectory/img1.png
               img2.png
               img3.png
```

becomes

```
Directory001.pdf
OtherDirectory.pdf
```

while only use img2pdf to do this, as it is by far the fastest way create the pdfs. I have some simple bash experience, but only with simple one liners (like turning all directories to zips). I know this can be done, but have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

To batch a command over a lot of files or directories, you often use find -exec like this :

```
find . -type d -exec "img2pdf" "{}"/* -o "{}".pdf ";"
```

this method is the most flexible, but in your case, you could as well use a simple loop :

```
for i in ./*/
   do img2pdf "$i"/* "$i.pdf"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xf
TOPDIR=$PWD
dirs=($(find . -type d))
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  #echo $dir
  cd $dir
  #echo $PWD
  img2pdf --out $dir.pdf *.jpg
  cd $TOPDIR
done
```